# PCI USB controller cards. Same but different(cheap electronics)?

Tags: capacitor, usb

I recently needed to order few more PCI USB controller cards and I had a few laying around already(I need to connect many USB cameras).
What surprised me is the difference in design and more importantly missing capacitors on the cards that I recently purchased(Asonic). They are from different manufacturers so different design is to be expected. But what I see is clearly a much poorer product, those recent cards. The price was the same.

Here are some pictures:

**Delock:**
[image: Delock]

**Asonic:**
[image: Asonic]

So my questions are, what can I expect performance wise?

What's the purpose of those capacitors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second is keyed as a 5V only pci card, and the first (with the caps) is keyed as a universal (3.3 and 5v) pci card, I suspect the extra components, and the electrolytic caps in particular, are for power filtering/regulation/conversion so the card can be used in both 3.3v and 5v pci slots.

I would suspect both work equally well, usb is a pretty standard component for ODM's to make and its not hard to make it work, I wouldn't expect it to have any kind of performance impact on a defined communications standard like usb.